# Elegant and clear way to name a thread-safe function?

Tags: naming-conventions

I'm looking for a naming convention for thread safe functions, meaning functions that can be called safely from multiple threads. But suppose I use :

void FooThreadSafe();

In your mind, do you think that :

This function will use locking mechanism and is safe to call concurrently ?

Or

This function can be called ONLY in a thread safe context ?

To me it's the first option, but many people think it's the second option. So I'm looking for a way to make it clear that you don't have to lock to call the function. Any idea ?

Thanks,

Noisetier

Answer (score 1):

Java uses `Atomic` or `Concurrent` as prefix.

For example `AtomicReference<>`, `ConcurrentHashMap<>`.